# suryveyor gem how to output the survey in pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, surveyor-gem

I read about the surveyor gem and in the webpage http://nubic.github.io/surveyor/

Where do I put this line to export the survey report to a pdf?

`%li= link_to "PDF", view_my_survey_path(:survey_code => response_set.survey.access_code, :response_set_code => response_set.access_code, :format => 'pdf')`

I am not understanding please help.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the website that you supplied you should have generated the `surveyor:custom` controllers. From this it then tells you to install the two following gems

```
  gem 'pdfkit'
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf'
```

But personally I prefer to use `wicked_pdf` in my opinion. So slightly changing the tutorial a little I would do the following:

```
rails generate surveyor:custom
```

This will generate the controllers. So then we can later configure this using the options that `wicked_pdf` will supply us.

Add the following lines to your Gemfile:

```
    gem 'wicked_pdf'  #https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf
    gem 'wkhtmltopdf' #https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
```

In order to have `wicked_pdf` export correctly you need to have something like this inside an action in your `surveyor controller` that is generated for you. So you may have something like this in your `index` action of your surveyor_controller.rb

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "Survey Report",
               :header => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'}}

      end
    end
```

From this respond block you could/should I think have the following directory in `views` - `app/views/survey/index.html.erb` Inside the `index.html.erb` you would then have your above link inside this.

```
<%= link_to "PDF", view_my_survey_path(:survey_code => 
response_set.survey.access_code, :response_set_code => 
                     response_set.access_code, :format => 'pdf') %>
```

I have never used the surveyor gem before. But based upon what you have supplied, and what you want I have tried to give as much of a detailed explanation as I can. Hope this potentially helps you or anyone else

**Example of Wicked_PDF usage**

```
 def index 
    @bookings= Booking.scoped
    booking = @bookings
    @user = current_user

    if params[:format] == 'pdf'
      @bookings= @bookings.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{Date.today.strftime('%B')} Overtime Report",
               :header => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'}}
        OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(@user, booking).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

**View.html.erb**

```
<%= Link_to "Overtime", "booking.png",  bookings(:format => "pdf") %>
```

In order to generate the PDF you need to create a file which has the following extension `.pdf.erb` what this means is that when the link is processed it processes the embedded ruby code first and then outputs PDF. So in this case I want to do bookings. So I did created in my `views/bookings/index.pdf.erb` inside this I have the following:

**views/bookings/index.pdf.erb**

```
<br />
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>

<p>
  <b>Employee</b>
  <%= booking.user.try (:full_name)%>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Hospital</b>
  <%= booking.hospital.try(:name)%>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Day</b>
  <%= booking.day.to_s(:long_ordinal) %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Overtime</b>
  <%= booking.overtime %>
</p>
    <br />
 <% end %>

<h2>Total Overtime is <b><%=@bookings.to_a.sum(&:overtime)%></b></h2>
```

This should give you some core grounds to work off of

Comment: Hi David, I tried like you said but I have faced some problems: 1) I dont find `/views/survey/index.html.erb` and also the respond block has an extra `end`. If you have the real code that you worked on explaining the answer please give the link. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Clone As I have mentioned I have not used the `surveyor gem` before but am greatly able to give you an example of how I use `wicked_pdf` hopefully this may potentially clear things up. See update